# E/flutter ( 7460): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: database, flutter, sqlite, debugging, null

I am a new learner and I not familiar to solve this issue. Anyone know how to solve this issue, please mention how to modify the line. Thank you.

Below are the code link:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1C-Y6Lanbky5zD_n_jKIR5UzpwcvOXbP-?usp=share_link

`````
E/flutter ( 7460): #0      DBHelper.query
db_helper.dart:42
E/flutter ( 7460): #1      TaskController.getTasks
task_controller.dart:23
E/flutter ( 7460): #2      _HomePageState._addTaskBar.<anonymous closure>
home_page.dart:151
E/flutter ( 7460): <asynchronous suspension>````

Hope you guys help me debug it. Another curiosity is that this will caused it cannot store in SQLite database, I not sure is my create database statement wrong or this issue causing it. Guys, please help me.
`````

Comment: post your code for clarity, you seem to be using this "!" for a value that is null,  this is most likely related to you TaskController.getTasks method.

Comment: I have attached the source code in the link above, please help me have a look on it and point it out, thank you.

Comment: Hello, any update? I still can't solved it, please help me. Thank you.

Comment: @Godson, please reply, I still wait for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This error mean that you use a null check operator `!` on a var that is null.

So by adding `!` you say this var is never null, but in fact this var is null.

if you provide source code i can point you where the error is.

Comment: I have attached the source code file in the link that attached above as it is too long I unable to paste it here. Aprreciate your help to point it out

Comment: Well, you have send all your source code, you should only send a code snippet of the code that cause the error message.

Comment: but it did not show which line in the file that trigger the error, so I send all the source code. Hopefully, you can help me define which part is having error and change it. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, any update? I still can't solved it, please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, I still wait for your reply. Please have a look, thank you.